# can't access user control public properties

Tags: function, controls, public

I am using VS2008 with both VB.NET and C#

I have created a simple custom user control and have added some public functions to it

my problem is that if I don't drag and drop the user control from the toolbox onto a winform but instead I try to create one dynamically via code - I am not able to access the public functions and properties

I can't understand why there would be a difference but htere seems to be.

would appreciate any help on the matter

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are defining your variable as type `UserControl`. As such, intellisense is only going to show you the members of the `UserControl` class, even if it is in fact of type `myCustomControl`.

Change your initial declaration to `myCustomControl myUC;` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You neeed to type cast to the usercontrol type 
then it works 
For Ex :

```
public partial class uctls_contact_uctlCompanyViewContacts : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
public bool ReadOnlyMode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

UserControl uctlCompanyViewContacts = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("uctlCompanyViewContacts.ascx");
uctlCompanyViewContacts.ID = "uctlCompanyViewContacts";
panelCompanyViewContacts.Controls.Add(uctlCompanyViewContacts);
((uctls_contact_uctlCompanyViewContacts)uctlCompanyViewContacts).ReadOnlyMode = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the LoadControl method to load the control?

ie.

```
MyControl ctrl = (MyControl)LoadControl("~/MyControl.ascx");
```

Comment: I add a using statement at the top of the form class e.g

using myUserControls

I define a variable as type user control at the top of my form class e.g

UserControl myUC;

then in the load event i assign it to my custom usercontrol like this

myUC = new MyUserControls.myCustomControl();

this.controls.add(myUC);

myUC.show();

everything up to this point works fine

I see the user control on the form but for some reason if i want to access a public function like:

myUC.ShowDetails()

the autocomplete doesn't show me the function at all 

Hope this makes sense